# Uncaught ReferenceError: user_id is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, symfony

what i Need

- I Need to call function from href .

html code

```
 <a href="#" onclick="peopleattending('.$_COOKIE['user'].', '.$_COOKIE['evnt_id'].');">
```

js code

```
         <script>

        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            function peopleattending(user_id,event_id)
            {

                console.log(user_id);
                console.log(event_id);

                 $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"{{get_hash_attend(user_id,event_id) }}", 
                     success: function(data)
                     {
                           $("#attend").text("Attending");



                    }
                });

            }

             peopleattending(user_id,event_id);


         });

        </script>
```

problem

- problem  Uncaught ReferenceError: user_id is not defined in  peopleattending(user_id,event_id);
- though im getting values say user_id=112223 and event_id=9.
- where im wrong if passing values in function in url : get_hash_attend(user_id,event_id)  same error appears.

Comment: when you are calling `peopleattending(user_id,event_id);` just above the closing brackets of `document.ready` ... there `user_id` and `event_id` is not defined,the scope of `user_id` and `event_id` is inside `peopleattending(...)` function.

Comment: try to put the `peopleattending` function outside of document.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_id` and `event_id` are only defined as parameters within your `peopleattending` function. when you call the code like this:

```
peopleattending(user_id,event_id);
```

Your basically saying

```
peopleattending(undefined,undefined);
```

You could set your variables on pageload within your javascript block instead of within your anchor tag's function reference

```
<script>
    var _user_id = '<?php $_COOKIE['user'] ?>';
    var _event_id = '<?php $_COOKIE['evnt_id'] ?>';

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        function peopleattending(user_id,event_id)
        {
             console.log(_user_id);
             console.log(_event_id);

             $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"{{get_hash_attend(user_id,event_id) }}", 
                success: function(data)
                {
                       $("#attend").text("Attending");
                }
            });

        }

        peopleattending(_user_id,_event_id);

     });
</script>
```

And then your anchor tag would look like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="peopleattending(_user_id,_event_id);">
```

## For Symfony:

```
<script>
    var _user_id = '{% app.request.cookies.get('user') %}';
    var _event_id = '{% app.request.cookies.get('event_id') %}';
```

I note there was a typo in your question, `evnt_id` instead of `event_id`. If this typo is also in your code then you'll need to fix it or change it in the javascript

If your vars are numbers and not strings, you can remove the quotes

```
<script>
    var _user_id = {% app.request.cookies.get('user') %};
    var _event_id = {% app.request.cookies.get('event_id') %};
```

If you want to use JQuery to read the cookies directly you can use the [Cookie plugin for jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

```
<script>
    var _user_id = $.cookie("user");
    var _event_id = $.cookie("event_id");
```

Although at this point you could drop the variables and call `$.cookie("user")` directly anywhere its needed.

Comment: problem im having im using symphony framework how to use  var _user_id = '<?php $_COOKIE['user'] ?>';
    var _event_id = '<?php $_COOKIE['evnt_id'] ?>'; to get cookie in symphony i need to impelmnt this how ?

Comment: i have refr link: http://enarion.net/news/2012/access-cookies-in-a-twig-template-using-symfony2/

Comment: I'm not familiar with symfony, but it looks like `{% app.request.cookies["user"] %}` EDIT: actually `cookies.get` - I edited my answer above

Comment: i have used document.cookie

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to get cookies in Symfony, that should be all you need. However you should note that 1) you had a typo in your question, `evnt_id` instead of `event_id`. If this typo is also in your code then you'll need to fix it or change it in the code I provided and 2) if your vars are numbers and not strings you can leave out the quotes

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: peopleattending is not defined when i click on anchor element

Comment: now getting cookies but now problem im   doing  console.log(user_id);
             console.log(event_id); in peopleattending function  no data is shwon in console

Comment: sorry they should change also to `_user_id` & `event_id`

Comment: i need suggestion im appending url  http:domain///ticket_transaction/autosubmit_advance/"+evt_id/user+"?visitor_flag=1&source=get-direction-oneclick

Comment: i have now eventid and user  but url is not ok

Comment: now url : http://local-login.com/ticket_transaction/autosubmit_advance/0.012915232373744963?visitor_flag=1&source=get-direction-oneclick

Comment: problem is url in format : http:domain///ticket_transaction/autosubmit_advance/222/445?visitor_flag‌​=1&source=get-direction-oneclick

Comment: we're getting way off topic here. I fixed your original issue and I'd appreciate it if you accepted the answer. For the record, that slash needs to be in quotes `" + event_id + "/" + user_id + "...` otherwise you're actually *dividing* event_id by user_id. If you have any more issues you really need to start a new thread